# Keras, AIX360(LIME) - ValueError: the input array must be have a shape == (.., ..,[ ..,] 3)), got (28, 28, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to make some program using a model from Keras and then explain it with Lime explainer from AIX360 (which is just wrapper for the original LIME). All the data are MNIST grayscale digits. But in my case, I am not able to explain the instance because I can't figure out what to feed to the explainers.

My code:

```
!pip install aix360
!pip install tensorflow==2.2.0

from __future__ import print_function
import warnings
# Supress jupyter warnings if required for cleaner output
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import keras
import keras.layers

from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical # convert to one-hot-encoding
from keras.models import Sequential # Sequeantial layer addition

from aix360.algorithms.lime import LimeImageExplainer

print('Using keras:', keras.__version__)

# Load dataset
from keras.datasets import mnist
# Tuple of Numpy arrays: (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test).
(train, train_labels), (test, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

# save input image dimensions
img_rows = train.shape[1]
img_cols = train.shape[2]

# Get classes and number of values
value_counts = pd.value_counts(train_labels).sort_index()
num_classes = value_counts.count()

train = train/255
test = test/255

train = train.reshape(train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
test = test.reshape(test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols,1)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
      optimizer='adam',
      metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 128
epochs = 1

model.fit(train, train_labels,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(test, test_labels))

score = model.evaluate(test, test_labels, verbose=0)

print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

limeExplainer = LimeImageExplainer()

limeExplainer.explain_instance(test[0], model.predict_proba)
```

The last line is where the error is. Don't pay attention to how the model is trained, that is not a concern.

EDIT: edited code so it is hopefully runable in codelab (added second line)

EDIT2: To be complete:
tensorflow 2.2.0
keras 2.4.3
aix360 0.2.0

Comment: No experience with aix360 - but the error you received looks like the explainer is looking for an input in the shape `(batch_size, img_rows, img_cols, channels)` -- given that `channels == 3` it apperas the explainer is expecting an RGB (3 channel) image, not greyscaled images.

Comment: This explanation seems to be plausible - see [here](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime/blob/master/lime/lime_image.py): `image: 3 dimension RGB image. If this is only two dimensional, we will assume it's a grayscale image and call gray2rgb.`

Comment: @irudyak Used shape: (28,28) got error : ValueError: the input array must be have a shape == (.., ..,[ ..,] 3)), got (1, 28, 28)

Comment: I would convert those images to RGB before training the model and check channels order in `lime`. Can you use `tf.keras` instead of `keras` with `lime`? I have issues with reproducing your code - too many deprecations.

Comment: This trick of repeating the one channel is often used in transfer learning when we use pre-trained on RGB models.  And usually we may get a correct classification of images. In your case you should look at results of this explainer. If they are reasonable you may go with this trick. In any case I would also try to use grayscale images and compare results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this conversion and trained on RGB images:

```
def to_rgb(x):
    x_rgb = np.zeros((x.shape[0], 28, 28, 3))
    for i in range(3):
        x_rgb[..., i] = x[..., 0]
    return x_rgb

train_rgb = to_rgb(train)
test_rgb = to_rgb(test)
```

And it worked:

```
limeExplainer.explain_instance(test_rgb[0], model.predict_proba)
100%
1000/1000 [00:00<00:00, 2598.51it/s]
<lime.lime_image.ImageExplanation at 0x7f8d20381f50>
```

Comment: this works, thank you! does it change anything that it is now in rgb instead of grayscales?